# Why does Yahoo Weather limit my wife to 2 locations but not me

Tags: weather

Yahoo Weather allows me to add any number of locations.

When my wife, on the very same Nexus 5 phone, tries to add a third location, it asks her to delete one of her existing locations.

What's going on?

Comment: Have you checked if you and your wife are using the same version of Yahoo Weather?

Comment: I have checked.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a transient bug in an app.

Comment: And how would I, or anyone else, know that in advance? I mean, go ahead and close, but it seems a strange criterion.

Comment: When you say *"on the very same Nexus 5 phone"*, do you mean that your wife also has a Nexus 5 phone, or did you create a second user profile on the same Nexus 5?

Comment: A second identical phone.

Comment: Could you post screenshots?

Comment: No, this was fixed on Aug 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing and reinstalling Yahoo! Weather on my wife's phone cured this. I guess Cousin Yahoo! has a bug.